# Printing current display screen windows phone 8.1

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a application using xamarin forms. The user must answer some questions at the end of the process I am displaying a summary for the user. I would like to give the user the option to print this page. the application is currently created on xamarin forms (windows 8.1) What would be the best way to achieve this goal.